# Number of permutations such that each number is either greater than all the numbers to its left or less than all the numbers to its right.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations, recursion, combinatorial-proofs

I've been stuck on the following problem which I've been trying to do recursively.

Let n be a positive integer. Consider all permutations of
$\{1, 2, \dots , n \}$. Let $A_n$ denote the set of those permutations such
that each number is either greater than all of the numbers to its
left or less than all of the numbers to its right. Let $B_n$ denote the
set of those permutations $a_1,\dots a_n$ such that for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$,
there is a $j > i$ with $|a_j -a_i| = 1$. Show that $|A_n| = |B_n|$.

I've been trying to do this recursively by showing there's the same recursion on $|A_n|$ and $|B_n|$ but I haven't been able to go anywhere. My first thought was that $|A_n| = n|A_{n-1}|$ because $n$ can be in any position of the permutation; $n$ can be in any position because it's always greater than the elements to it's left. But this recursion would lead to $|A_n| = n!$ which is clearly not true. However I don't see what I'm missing here, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on your question, I'm interpreting the condition that the leftmost number is the permutation is considered to be greater than all the numbers to its left (of which there are none), and similarly for the rightmost number.

Comment: Regarding the $|A_n|=n|A_{n-1}|$ conjecture, this doesn't quite work because if we take a permutation on $n-1$ satisfying your conditions, $n$ can go anywhere and it will satisfy your conditions, but it could cause other elements to stop satisfying your conclusion. Eg take $1,2,\ldots,n-1$. Everything is greater than the numbers to its left. But if we plop $n$ down on the very left, only $n$ will be greater than the numbers to its left after that. So you could try to count how many permutations are broken in such a way.

Comment: But if we take away $n$ from any good permutation of $A_n$ we still get a "good" permutation right?

Comment: Yes. A "bad" permutation must have $\sigma(p)>\sigma(q)>\sigma(r)$ for some $p<q<r$. No matter where you insert $n$, these three will still be bad. So inserting $n$ can't create goodness. By contraposition, deleting $n$ can't create badness.

Comment: Thanks, I think that maybe only $n$ or $1$ can be on the last position of the permutation but I'm not sure how to prove that

Comment: On reflection, puzzled. $A_3$ has 123 132 213 231 312, hence 5 members (321 excluded because 2 doesn’t fit). $B_3$ has 123 132 312 321, hence 4 members (213 and 231 fail on $i=2$). What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2):

Only half an answer but too long for a comment.

$|A|=2^n-n$

A “good” permutation is a set of numbers you select, written in ascending order, followed by the numbers you didn’t select, also in ascending order.

Each number selection corresponds to a unique good permutation *except* that selections $\{\}$, 1, 12, 123, etc all correspond to the same permutation (the super-good one, where everything is in one ascending sequence).

Selectedness is a yes-or-no decision, so there are $2^n$ possible selections. The supergood permutation corresponds to $n+1$ selections, so we have to subtract $n$ from this total.

You can verify this by hand for values of $n$ from 4 down to 1. Or even 0 if you want.

Comment: 'A “good” permutation is a set of numbers you select, written in ascending order, followed by the numbers you didn’t select, also in ascending order' is not correct.

Comment: The permutation $(3142)$ is good, so this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make this any cleaner. Let $\sigma$ be a permutation on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. There exist unique intervals $I_1,\ldots,I_t$ such that $\max I_i<\min I_{i+1}$ for all $1\leqslant i<t$, $\sigma|_{I_i}$ is increasing, and $\sigma(\max I_i)>\sigma(\min I_{i+1})$ for all $1\leqslant i<t$.  That is, we partition $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ into the maximum intervals on which it's increasing.

For subsets $R,S$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, we let $R<S$ denote the relation that $r<s$ for all $r\in R$ and $s\in S$.

When we describe a $\sigma$, it is sufficient to provide the ranges $\sigma(I_1)$, $\sigma(I_2)$, $\ldots$, $\sigma(I_t)$, because we know that $\sigma$ maps $I_i$ to $\sigma(I_i)$ in a strictly increasing way. So in order to define a $\sigma$, it is necessary and sufficient to provide a partition $C_1,\ldots, C_t$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. This determines a $\sigma$ by letting $I_1,\ldots, I_t$ be the interval partition of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $I_1<\ldots<I_t$ and $|I_i|=|C_i|$. Then $\sigma$ maps $I_i$ to $C_i$ in a strictly increasing way.

There is one permutation with $t=1$ increasing interval $I_1$, the identity permutation, which is good.

As was mentioned in the other answer, there are $2^n-(n+1)$ good permutations which have two increasing intervals. These are obtained by choosing a subset $A$ of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ to be the range $\sigma(I_1)$, and then $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ is forced to be the range $\sigma(I_2)$.  However, $n+1$ choices of $A$ are actually re-counting the $t=1$ permutation above. These are $A=\varnothing,\{1\},\{1,2\},\ldots, \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Let's consider $t>2$. Let $I_1,\ldots, I_t$ be the intervals of increase of a good permutation $\sigma$. Let $P=\sigma(I_1)$ be the range of the first interval and let $Q=\sigma(I_t)$ be the range of the last interval. Let $p=\max P$ and $q=\min Q$.

It must be the case that $P\cup Q$ is an interval and there exist $A_1<\ldots <A_m<Q$ and $P<B_m<\ldots<B_1$ such that $P,Q,A_1,\ldots,A_m,B_1,\ldots,B_m$ forms a partition of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ and the ranges $\sigma(I_1),\sigma(I_2),\ldots, \sigma(I_t)$ are, in order, $P,A_1\cup B_1,A_2\cup B_2,\ldots, A_m\cup B_m,Q$. Every member of $P$ is greater than the entries to the left (because it is the first interval of increase), every member of $Q$ is less than the entries to the right of it (because it is the last interval of increase), every member of $A_i$ is less than the entries to the right of it (because those are either other members of $A_i$ to the right (which are good because $A_i$ is an interval of increase), or members of $A_{i+1},B_{i+1},\ldots, A_m,B_m,Q$, all of which are greater than every member of $A_i$. Every member of every $B_i$ is greater than every entry to the right for similar reasons.

We've sketched how we know that any such $\sigma$ is good. I'm going to omit the details that any good $\sigma$ must be of this form.

Comment: This isn't a good answer, it relies on the answer you just said it's wrong

Comment: No it doesn't. If you read my answer carefully (which I recommend you do before commenting on it), you'll see that the reason the other answer is wrong is that it says "good permutations consist of at most two ascending sections", which is wrong. Then Martin went on to correctly count the number of permutation which have at most two ascending sections. The reason his answer is wrong is that this misses some good permutations. My answer uses his count, which is a correct count of a subset of good permutations, and then goes on to describe the good permutations his answer missed.

Comment: In other words, let $A_n$ be the good permutations on $n$ and let $T_n$ be the permutations on $n$ with at most two ascending sections. The other answer has two parts: Claiming that $A_n=T_n$ (which is wrong), and claiming that $|T_n|=2^n-n$ (which is correct). My answer only uses that $|T_n|=2^n-n$. It then goes on to describe $A_n\setminus T_n$.